# Why REST module didn't return me a session confirmation number?

Tags: atg

I have a question. I have a REST module in my ATG in j2ee-apps I have ear atg rest file.
[image]

But when I'm trying to get session confirmation number I have this error

[image]

What's the problem? What did I do wrong and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Can you open dyn/admin and check ActorChainRestRegistry component for registered URL. You might have to add the url.

Can you post error logs.